# sql - Nested select on SQL compact

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following little query that produces a parsing error. I am trying to select a group of player id's and then select the data of those player id's.

My question is, what is the correct way to use a nested select in SQL compact?

```
"SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GRADE, WON, LOST, SKILL 
 FROM player 
 WHERE ID = (SELECT player1 
             FROM temp_table 
             WHERE school = 0)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing `ID =` with `ID IN`